# Wordpress/PHP/Ajax Load More não mostra os posts no Windows

Tags: ajax, wordpress, windows, load

Eu tenho uma página de Timeline no meu site e uso o plugin Ajax Load More pra usar o scroll infinito. Ele está funcionando perfeitamente no servidor local quando testo no Ubuntu e em dispositivos Mobile, mas quando testo em qualquer dispositivo que use Windows não aparece nenhum post. Alguém pode me ajudar?